# Laravel scheduler выполняется по 2-3 раза на сервере(ubuntu crontab)

Tags: laravel, cron, crontab, scheduler

Всем привет! У меня есть несколько команд созданных в laravel. Они вносят информацию в базу данных и таблицу логов. Берут информацию по url (некоторые работают по несколько минут). Чтобы их запустить я решил использовать laravel scheduler. Прописал команды в Kernel:

```
$schedule->command('import:mls')->dailyAt('00:00');
$schedule->command('import:MLS_Yandex_Services_CFG')->dailyAt('00:05');
$schedule->command('import:MLS_Yandex_Services_To_Table')->dailyAt('00:10');
$schedule->command('import:MLS_Cian_Services_To_Table')->dailyAt('00:15');
$schedule->command('import:mlsCFG')->dailyAt('00:20');
$schedule->command('make:MLSfeed')->dailyAt('00:25');
$schedule->command('get:all_ext_api_offers')->everyTenMinutes();
$schedule->command('get:all_mls_ext_api_offers')->everyFifteenMinutes();
//allFeed
$schedule->command('import:can_ya_leads')->dailyAt('04:00');
$schedule->command('make:Feed')->dailyAt('05:00');
```

И в моём ubuntu на сервере в crontab я добавил запуск шелудера (как сказано в документации). Запуск производится из контейнера приложения:

- - - - - docker exec can-service-app php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Проблема в том, что я вижу в таблице логов выполнение команд шелудера по 2-3 раза!В бд запись тоже производится несколько раз за одну команду. Я пробовал найти проблему сам: запускал команды из консоли убунту(всё нормально 1 раз), создал тест команду с 1 запросом на вставку в логи(она выполнилась 2-3 раза так-же). Я уже и по одной команде оставлял и ставил withoutOverlapping и всё равно 2-3 раза или вообще не выполнялись.

Есть мысли что сервер каким-то магическим образом лагает и выполняет по 2-3 команды сразу! Но как это возможно? Я уже не знаю как быть!

Comment: процесс php внутри контейнера can-service-app запускается раз в минуту. вот, видимо, и наплодилось дубликатов процессов.

Comment: но почему тогда их всегда 2-3? причём всегда!) вне зависимости от сложности команды. тут что-то нечистое кроется..может какая-то настройка чего-то..я даже не знаю как описать это..